# How to restart openvpn in pfsense?

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

The OpenVPN Status page on the pfSense shows the following error:

```
[error] Management Daemon Unreachable
```

Disabling then enabling the configured VPN does not resolve this.  How do you restart the daemon?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the openvpn daemon was dying on a bad CRL file.  I've consoled into the pfsense, commented the #daemon option in the conf file and started the service manually to identify the error:

```
/usr/local/sbin/openvpn --config /var/etc/openvpn/server1.conf
```

For restarts, you can always kill this process and start it from the console.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was I had a typo in the `Advanced Configuration -> Custom options` section.

I found out by looking at the openvpn logs:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /var/etc/openvpn/server1/config.ovpn:43: psuh (2.5.2)
```

Fixing the typo in the custom options, and restarting the OpenVPN service fixed it.